# LDAP schema edit

Tags: ldap, automount, schema

I have default LDAP schema (389 DS instance) with the following objectClasses:

```
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.17 NAME 'automount' DESC 'An entry in an automo
 unter map' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ automountInformation ) MAY descript
 ion X-ORIGIN 'draft-howard-rfc2307bis' )
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.16 NAME 'automountMap' DESC 'An group of relate
 d automount objects' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ou X-ORIGIN 'draft-howard-rfc230
 7bis' )
```

I need modify thoses classes for using automount on a Solaris clients to the next state:

```
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.16 NAME 'automountMap' DESC 'Automount Map information' SUP top
 STRUCTURAL MUST automountMapName MAY description X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.17 NAME 'automount' DESC 'Automount information' SUP top STRUCTURAL
 MUST ( automountKey $ automountInformation ) MAY description X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
```

AttributeTypes `automountKey` and `automountMapName` has been added by me.
But I not able edit objectClasess automount and automountMap. Via GUI console edit button is not clickable. Via ldapmodify I gets unexpected error:

> ldapmodify: invalid format (line 5) entry: "cn=schema"

I think my ldif file looks correct:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: objectclasses
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.16
 NAME 'automountMap'
 DESC 'Automount Map information'
 SUP top
 STRUCTURAL
 MUST automountMapName
 MAY description
)

objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.17
 NAME 'automount'
 DESC 'Automount information'
 SUP top
 STRUCTURAL
 MUST (automountKey $ automountInformation)
 MAY description
)
```

How can I edit those objectClasses? Is it possible?
Or how can I redefine those objectClasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround.
I edited schema files in /etc/dirsrv/slapd-centos/schema

Answer (score 1):

You just didn't choose the right dn.

Instead of `dn: cn=schema` you should have chosen `cn=schema,cn=config`.

Still in my opinion it would be better to define a custom schema, which you can put right under this dn. So instead of adding it to `cn=schema,cn=config`, you would do something like this:

`ldapadd -xWD cn=admin,cn=config
dn: cn=<schemaName>,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: <schemaName>
olcObjectClasses: ...`